# Convergence of a continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a jordan domain.

I want to answer the following problem, please help me:

Consider an increasing sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\partial G\to \mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N},$ that is uniformly bounded above.

let $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$  be the solution of the Direchlet problem for $f_n$ in $G$.

Show that the corresponding sequence of functions $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$ converges localy uniformly on $G$ to a function $u$ harmonic in $G$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First use the maximum principle to get that the sequence $u_n$ is an increasing sequence of harmonic functions that is moreover uniformly bounded above.

Then use the mean value formula to conclude that the pointwise limit (which always exists) is harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and increasing sequence then $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ such that $\int_{\partial D}|f|dz$ is finite.

hence we chould prove that $u_n: \bar{\Bbb{D}} \to \Bbb{R}$:

$$ u_n(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1 - e^{-it}z|^2} f_n ( e^{it}) \, dt, \qquad z \in \Bbb{D}. $$
converges locally uniformlly to $u: \bar{\Bbb{D}} \to \Bbb{R}$
$$ u(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1 - e^{-it}z|^2} f( e^{it}) \, dt, \qquad z \in \Bbb{D}. $$

Can someone help me to sho that please?